# FlaskApp Running with Apache unable to save file on server side can't get permission to work out?

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have a flask app running at /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/**init**.py

```
├── /var/www/FlaskApp
├── FlaskApp
|   ├── flask (This is a virtual environment with python3.4 and packages)
│   ├── __init__.py
├──flaskapp.wsgi 
├── config.py
```

My **init**.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

@app.route('/upload, methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload(machine):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                f = request.files['files']
                filename = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles/myfile.txt

                #Some how there is an error saving the file here...???!!! WHY 
                f.save(filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I read the apache error log and I see that it is a permission error:

```
[Fri Dec 09 12:08:11.371696 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3425:tid 1962931248] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles/myfile.txt
```

So I was thinking that somehow the apache user coulden't get access to this directory. Just to mess around I figured what the heck, lets see if chmod 777 will fix this. So I did this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/
```

However I still got the error when I would try to upload the file. This is how I am trying to upload the file:

```
curl -i -X POST -F files=@/pathtomyfile.txt myip/upload/
```

I am wondering how to fix the permission error. I have tried adding absolute paths and I also tried the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod go-rwx /var/www
```

However I haven't been able to get away from this error. Here is my FlaskApp.conf from apache:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/bin
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName my ip (this is local)
                ServerAdmin my email
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am looking into insight as to why I get the error for permission denied when I try to save the file that I am attempting to upload to my server.

Ok here are some more outputs:

```
ls -ldg /var/www/
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 www-data 4096 Dec  7 10:31 /var/www/

ls -ldg /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 0 Nov 23 07:54 /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles
```

Comment: Try to manually create the `static` and `runFiles` directories. See if the error changes.

Comment: Check the process ownership. Make sure they have access to the files.

Comment: `Apache` mostly runs as user `www-data` and this user needs access to folders.

Comment: How do I explicitly give access to the folders? I have tried `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if you mentioned this but I don't see it: what user is the apache process running as? Are you sure it is the www-data user?

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod go-rwx /var/www
```

By doing that ^ you have locked it down so nobody except www-data user can do anything with the files. Even the www-data group wont be able to access because `go-rwx` means "Deny rwx permission for group, others".

Finally for troubleshooting, what is the output from these?

```
ls -ldg /var/www/
ls -ldg /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles
ls -l /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/runFiles/myfile.txt
```

Comment: I posted the outputs to the original question. the myfile.txt is not in the directory since I was not able to save it there so that directory is blank

Comment: In the output I put on the original question one is it saying that www-data actually doesn't have access to the directory I am trying to save since the user listed is root?

Comment: runFiles/ is owned by root, and not writable by anyone else. The weird thing is, you said you did `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`. What created that directory as owned by root? In any case, this seems like basically a directory permissions issue. Apache + Flask user (check with ps -aux?) needs to fit the directory permissions :)

Comment: I have found out that the folder I am trying to save into was another drive that was mounted to `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static` the command to do this was inside of `/etc/rc.local` so I think that is where it gets the `root` ownership. How would I change this mount so I could use the same drive just have it owned by www-data? I am looking into this.

Comment: Probably need to check `/etc/fstab`  file and maybe modify the settings there. or change the mount command in the script. Either way should work!